# Is it possible to sync questions and answers that I post in sites with RSS feeds to Twitter?

Tags: twitter, rss, automation, twitter-integration

How can sync I my Twitter and Stack Exchange accounts together so that the questions and answers that I post to all of Stack Exchange sites, with have RSS feeds, are auto tweeted to my Twitter?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can use [IFTTT](http://ifttt.com) and create a recipe that goes from a "Feed" to Twitter.

Create a recipe:

[image]

Select the feed option:

[image]

Select the "new item in feed" option:

[image]

You can find your RSS feed for Stack Overflow by going to your profile page and scrolling down to the lower right corner.

It looks like you have to do this for each site, as I can't find a feed for all of one's Stack Exchange posts.

[image]

Connect it to the Twitter endpoint, etc.  For the Twitter parameters, you'll want:

> My latest Stack Overflow post {{EntryUrl}} {{EntryContent}}

in the tweet, as the `{{Entry Title}}` only says "Answer on blah blah" I don't know how it handles the {{EntryContent}} and whether it is truncated if too long.

This will only tweet new items on your feed, it won't tweet any old posts.  In addition, a caveat: it also posts comments that you make.